# Permanent of a square block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, matching-theory, permanent

I've run into the following expression involving the permanent of a matrix:
$$
\operatorname{per}\left(
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\ I & C
\end{array}
\right]
\right)
$$
Where $A$ and $C$ are diagonal matrices, $B$ is a dense matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix. All of them are $n\times n$ matrices.

I'm not very familiar with the properties of the permanent, but can in this case be expressed in terms of the blocks $A, B$ and $C$?
As far as I've read, there is no general rule for the permanent of a block matrix in terms of the different blocks, but since this is a particular case (with diagonals matrices) there may be a formula.

I think this should hold:
$$
\operatorname{per}\left(
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\ I & C
\end{array}
\right]
\right)
=
\operatorname{per}\left(
AC +B
\right)
$$

What if $C$ is not diagonal?